# Rosserial multiple publishers

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04, rosserial, hydro.

Using an arduino uno, the following code works and publishes messages:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;
std_msgs::Int16 ultrasound_msg;
std_msgs::Int16 ir_msg;
ros::Publisher ultrasound_pub("ultrasound", &ultrasound_msg);
ros::Publisher infrared_pub("infrared", &ir_msg);


void setup() {
  // Initialize sensors, etc
    nh.initNode();
    nh.advertise(ultrasound_pub);
    //nh.advertise(infrared_pub);
}

void loop() {
  
  ultrasound_msg.data = 42;
  ultrasound_pub.publish( &ultrasound_msg );
  
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
  
}
```

If I un-comment the second advertise:

```
void setup() {
  // Initialize sensors, etc
    nh.initNode();
    nh.advertise(ultrasound_pub);
    nh.advertise(infrared_pub);
}
```

I get 'Creation of publisher failed: unpack requires a string argument of length 4', when I try to start the node on the ROS side.

When I try to initialize only the second publisher:

```
void setup() {
  // Initialize sensors, etc
    nh.initNode();
    //nh.advertise(ultrasound_pub);
    nh.advertise(infrared_pub);
}
```

Starting the node says 'Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino'

I saw 2 posts with similar problems, solved by updating the rosserial-arduino and rosserial installations.  I have fresh installations from apt-get, so I'm not sure why they'd be mismatched.

Any ideas?

UPDATE

If I replace the second publisher with a subscriber like so:

```
void ROS_CALLBACK(const std_msgs::Int16 &msg)
{
  // do stuff
}
ros::Publisher ultrasound_pub("ultrasound", &ultrasound_msg);
ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int16> sub("arduino_listener", &ROS_CALLBACK);
...
void setup() {
  // Initialize sensors, etc
    nh.initNode();
    nh.advertise(ultrasound_pub);
    nh.subscribe(sub);
}
```

I get the same errors for the same sequence.  'Failed to unpack' for the code shown below.  'Unable to sync with device' if I advertise subscribe without advertising the publisher.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87016/rosserial-multiple-publishers/) by [stebl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7311/stebl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-10-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stebl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7311/stebl/) on 2013-10-04**:
Rolling back the rosserial libraries to 0.5.1 provides a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed in latest rosserial source. New release of rosserial debs coming out in the next few days. See [Issue 76](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/76) for an explanation of the problem. In a nutshell, an uninitialized data situation was introduced, which caused the upper two bytes of string length to contain random data. The fault was introduced in 0.5.2, which explains why 0.5.1 works.

---

Originally posted by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) with karma: 300 on 2013-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stebl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7311/stebl/) on 2013-10-14**:
confirmed working :)